# downloading web page using NSURLDownload

Tags: objective-c, download

here is my code, it tries to download a webpage using NSURLDownload. but it does not work, its a command line program.

```
- (void)startDownloadingURL
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/index.html"]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the download with the request and start loading the data.
    NSURLDownload  *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theDownload) {
        // Set the destination file.
        [theDownload setDestination:@"/saleh" allowOverwrite:YES];
    } else {
        // inform the user that the download failed.
        NSLog(@"download has failed!");
    }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  Does it print `download has failed!`?  Did you implement any [NSURLDownloadDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLDownloadDelegate) methods like `downloadDidFinish:` or `download:didFailWithError:`?

Comment: it does not give me any error! i have implemented the delegates, but they seem do not work! i have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you implement the downloadDidFinish and doanload:didFailWithError: callbacks.

Here's an overview that covers how to use NSURLDownload:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839-BAJEAIEE

Specifically, this callback will give you more details on why it failed:

```
- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection.
    [download release];

    // Inform the user.
    NSLog(@"Download failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

EDIT:

Below you said it's a command line.  async callbacks require an NSRunLoop.  See:

[Cocoa: NSURLConnection not attempting an HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267163/cocoa-nsurlconnection-not-attempting-an-http-request)

Per the docs:

initWithRequest:delegate:
Returns an initialized URL download for a URL request and begins to download the data for the request.

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate
```

> **delegate**
>
> The delegate for the download. This object will receive delegate
>   messages as the download progresses. Delegate messages will be sent on
>   the thread which calls this method. For the download to work correctly
>   the calling thread’s run loop must be operating in the default run
>   loop mode.

NSURLConnection has a synchronous way to download data.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE

> NSURLConnection provides support for downloading the contents of an
>   NSURLRequest in a synchronous manner using the class method
>   sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:. Using this method is
>   not recommended, because it has severe limitations:

The main limitation is the client blocks but that's a concern in a command line app.

Comment: my program is command-line, why it does not download? since its not a GUI program cant use delegate!

Comment: a command line shouldn't matter - create a class that does the work (the downloading) which main.m calls.  That class needs to implement those delegate callbacks.

Comment: that is what i did, but since it did not work, i asked it in a forum and they said delegates work only in GUI programs not in command-line program. in my class below the above code i have implemented the delegates. but they dont work!

Comment: hmmm - delegate is just a callback that conforms to a protocol.  maybe there's something I'm missing.  I'll try it out and check back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you define at least `downloadDidFinish:` and 
`download:didFailWithError:` to use the delegate. You can pretty much just copy and paste the methods from the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html).

If you are on 10.7 you should declare that you use the protocol in your header as well, before Lion there wasn't a formal protocol.

Also make sure you have a run loop going. For testing you can just stick `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` in there, although it's probably not going to ever exit the loop then.