# Checking for NSRunLoop and using appropriate NSURLConnection method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I'm working on a personal project and ran into the asynchronous nature of NSURLConnection last night. I'm building a library that is going to interface with a restful api. I'm anticipating reusing this library, in both Foundation command line tools as well as Cocoa applications.

Is there a way I can either check if the runloop is available to call the synchronous method if it is, and send a synchronous request if it is not (in the event of being used in a command line tool).

Alternately, is there a way to always use the asynchronous method but force the application to not exit until the async request has finished?

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267392/949653) but I'd rather not have to put the call to run outside of the library.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Alternately, is there a way to always use the asynchronous method but force the application to not exit until the async request has finished?

Easy as pie:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    // Create request, delegate object, etc.
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                  delegate:delegate 
                                                          startImmediately:YES];
    CFRunLoopRun();
    // ...
}
```

I use `CFRunLoopRun()` here because it's possible to stop it later, when the delegate has determined that the connection is done:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // This returns control to wherever you called
    // CFRunLoopRun() from.
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

The other option is to use `-[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:]` in a while loop, and have the delegate set a "stop" flag:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                              delegate:delegate 
                                                      startImmediately:YES];

while( ![delegate connectionHasFinished] ){
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can check if the program is linked against AppKit by seeing if `NSClassFromString(@"NSApplication")` returns non-`Nil`.  Then, you can check if you're on the main thread using `+[NSThread isMainThread]`.

However, it's poor design for the library to try to "force" the app not to exit for whatever reason.  Just establish that the library requires the cooperation of the app and provide a cleanup-and-finish routine for it to call.  Possibly also a is-there-something-in-progress? function.